# get_option, intval, datatype

Tags: php, wordpress, int

My scripts run if I do:

```
$config['max'] = 20;
```

It doesn't run if I use the configuration-value of my plugin like

```
$config['max'] = get_option('plugin_max');
```

Also not like

```
$config['max'] = intval(get_option('plugin_max'));
```

In every case, if I print $config['max'], it prints

> 20

I think there must be some stupid datatype-mismatch, but I can't figure out what it could be.

**Solution**

ok, I have to clear this up and maybe it will help someone later on. The problem was that get_option was undefined because it was called directly in an AJAX-request. I now routed the ajax-requests properly over WPs admin-ajax.php function so that WP-functions are available to the plugin even when called from AJAX.
Strangely, while debugging, the function was available, but this might have been while initialising the plugin, which is of course no AJAX-request but entirely server-side and so inside the scope of WP by default.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: try `abs(get_option('plugin_max'));`

Comment: thanks, but no luck...

Comment: Did you try typecasting?

    $config['max'] = (int) get_option('plugin_max');

Comment: what does this return ? `get_option('plugin_max')` is it returning any thing try a `var_dumo(get_option('plugin_max'))` or you can also give it a try by assignint the option's value to variable then pass the variable to array

Comment: thanks for your help, I added the solution above...